# Как дозаписать файл в python

Tags: python, файлы

Я делаю телеграм-бота, и мне нужно записывать сообщения пользователя в файл txt. Но обычный метод .write() перезаписывает его, а мне это не нужно. Как **до**записать файл в python?

Comment: используйте `open(filename, mode="a")` ...

Comment: with open('file.txt', 'r+') as f: f.seek(0, 2) f.write('blabla') а там где f.seek 0 это номер буквы, а 2 строка? Или наоборот?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете открыть файл в режиме добавления `open('...', 'a')` и использовать привычный `.write()`. В этом случае запись будет осуществляться в конец.

А вообще запись в файл и чтение из него производятся в позиции некоего "курсора". Каждое действие над содержимым файла перемещает этот курсор. И если файл открыт в режиме "чтение и обновление" (`'r+'`), то можно переместить курсор в конец файла с помощью метода `.seek()` и записать что-то всё тем же `.write()`. Код, дописывающий строку в конце файла, будет выглядеть как-то так:

```py
with open('file.txt', 'r+') as f:
    # ...
    f.seek(0, 2)       # перемещение курсора в конец файла
    f.write('blabla')  # собственно, запись
```

Про метод seek можно почитать [тут](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.seek).

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
test=open('ПУТЬ К ФАЙЛУ//file.txt', 'a')
test.write('То, что вы хотите дозаписать')
test.close()
```

Comment: А как дописать текст в файл, перед заголовками?